# How to restart Apache with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

I have a Laravel 7 installation on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I can't find a way to restart Apache with a PHP script. (My goal is to create a cronjob that restarts the server every 24 hours.)

I added these lines to the **sudoers** file:

```
Cmnd_Alias RESTART_APACHE = /sbin/service apache2 restart
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: RESTART_APACHE
```

And I try to run this command:

```
exec('/sbin/service apache2 restart');
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Anything wrong with Apache? Why restart every 24h? Servers usually run for months/years without restarting. "_But it doesn't work_" _What_ doesn't work?! Any errors? Why use a intermediate PHP script and not run the command directly in your cron?!

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to reboot. Do you advise against it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your crontab

0 0 * * * [ your command ] to execute every day.

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more specific please? I would like to restart apache2 every day at midnight.

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/